# how to show that a ODE is negative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

So I have the ODE given by $-u''(x)=f(x;\lambda)$ for $x\in(0,1)$ with the boundary condition $u(0)=u(1)$ and the function is defined as $f(x;\lambda) = -\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $\lambda>0$. This has a unique solution in $C^2_0[0,1]=\{g\in C^2[0,1] \mid g(0)=g(1)=0\}$. How can I show (using Green's function) that $u(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$.

The general solution is given by $u''(x)=0$ with $u(x)=Ax+B$. But we have to also consider two cases, $x\in [0,y)$ and $x\in (y,1]$. I got that the system of equation as

$$G(x,y) = \begin{cases}Ax+B \qquad x\in [0,y) \\ Cx+D\qquad x\in (y,1]\end{cases}$$

Applying the boundary conditions I got that

$$G(x,y) = \begin{cases}Ax \qquad\qquad x\in [0,y) \\ C(x-1)\qquad x\in (y,1]\end{cases}$$

I know that I have to also consider $x=y$ where $Ax=C(x-1)$, I ended up solving $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}G'(x,y)-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-}G'(x,y)=1$$

This ended up giving me $x^2-x$ for both cases. Am I missing something?

**edit**

Sorry, I noticed the error. it should be $x(y-1)$ for $x<y$ and $y(x-1)$ for $x>y$, but I don't see how I can conclude that $u(x)\leq 0$ all the terms in the integral

$$u(x) = \int^1_0 G(x,y)f(y;\lambda) dy$$

looks negative, but I have $-u''(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Rolle's theorem says that $\exists c\in (0,1)$ such that $u'(c)=0$. Since $u''(c) > 0$, we must have that $u'$ is negative to the left of $c$ and positive to the right of $c$, so $u$ is decreasing on $(0,c)$ and hence is negative here.

We now just need to show that $u$ is never positive on $(c,1)$. Suppose there was another root of $u$, $d\in(c,1)$. Then again there is some number $e\in(d,1)$ such that $u'(e) = 0$, but if $u'(c) = u'(e) = 0$, then Rolle's theorem implies the existence of a number in $(c,e)$ where $u''$ is zero, a contradiction to $u'' >0$.

We have shown that $u$ is decreasing on $(0,c)$, so it is not positive since $u(0) = 0$, and that it only has two roots at $x=0,1$, so it can never become positive in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

By integrating the equation twice
$$
u(x)= \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}+ C_1x+C_2
$$
with the boundary conditions we obtain $$C_2=-\frac{1}{\lambda} \quad C_1=\frac{-e^{-\lambda}+1}{\lambda}$$

So the solution of the ODE is

$$
u(x)= \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}+\frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}x-\frac{1}{\lambda}
$$
the first derivative is
$$
u'(x)=-e^{-\lambda x}+\frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}
$$
It is equal to zero only in one point, namely
$$
x=\frac{1}{\lambda} \left(\log(\lambda)-\log(1-e^{-\lambda})\right)
$$
As the function is convex such point is a minimum point. But for Wiestrass theorem the function attains its maximum at some point of the compact set $[0,1]$ As it can't be any interior point (as the derivative would be zero in such point) the maximum has to be on the boundary. *i.e*
$$
u(x) \le \max(u(0),u(1))=0
$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have a question, how would you generally know that a ODE has at least two solutions?

Comment: @user8700908 There are theorems that guaranties unicity (Lipschitz coefficients) and theorems that guaranties only existence (Peano). But there are no result that guaranties that there is more than one solution. $\quad$

Moreover if there are 2 distinct solutions of a linear ODE there are infinite many

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is $c\in(0,1)$ such that $u(c)>0$. Then $u(x)$ reaches the maximum at some $x_0\in(0,1)$. So $u''(x_0)\le0$. However letting $x=x_0$ gives
$$ u''(x_0)=-f(x,\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x_0}>0 $$
which is contradictory to $u''(x_0)\le0$. Therefore $u(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.